# Derived variables in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am building a Django app that has a central Projects model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    fundamental_attrib1=models.IntegerField()
    fundamental_attrib2=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    derived_attrib1=models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    derived_attrib1_start=models.DateField(null=True)
    derived_attrib1_end=models.DateField(null=True)

    derived_attrib2=models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    derived_attrib2_start=models.DateField(null=True)
    derived_attrib2_end=models.DateField(null=True)

    derived_attrib3=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    derived_attrib3_start=models.DateField(null=True)
    derived_attrib3_end=models.DateField(null=True)
```

The goal is to allow users to instantiate new projects where they can only see (and only need to) the 'fundamental' variables in the form to create/update a Project. Once they have submitted the form, I want to be calculate all the optional parameters before saving the project to the database.

In addition, most of my derived variables come in groups of three as above (value, start date, end date). Is there a better way (that makes sense) to store them in the database? Naive string example:

```
{'derived_attrib1':[1000,date(2017,1,1),date(2017,2,2)]}
{'derived_attrib2':[2000,date(2017,2,1),date(2017,3,2)]}
{'derived_attrib3':[ 500,date(2017,3,1),date(2017,4,2)]}
```

My eventual 'end goal' is, for each group:

- create numpy arrays (or bring into one DataFrame?) to interpolate days between the start and end dates
- linearly distribute the value across the days
- plot each group as a timeseries (probably with D3.js/Bokeh or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these come in groups and can be seen as an entity, consider using [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). For other backends, one could use a json representation in a `TextField` (or one of the [json fields](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/fields/) that work in the same way). Field choice depends on what comes in from the calculation and what your processing is most comfy with.

The choice not to do this, would be if you frequently would filter querysets on attributes of these entities, as while that's possible, it's not as fast as querying straight fields. Relations will be impossible.

A totally different approach is to use OneToOne fields to models. This creates a ton of joins for your approach, so I'm not recommending it, but it has some advantages in terms of handling each derived entity: it's fields and calculation method are independent of the model that uses them.

Comment: Thanks - ArrayField would have been ideal although unfortunately it's not available for my SQL database(!)

Comment: `TextField` seems my best bet as you suggested. I've wrapped them as individual lists - does that make sense to do?: `[{"Label": "Derived Attrib#1", "start date": date(2017,1,1), "end date": date(2017,2,2)}]`

Comment: If this is `[{ attribute object}, {attribute object}, ...]` then yes. The list container doesn't serve a purpose if just wrapping one attribute object.

Answer (score 1):

I would say ForeignKey in a related model would be the best bet. Then you can query `Project.objects.filter(derived__start__gt=start, derived__end__lt=something)`. prefetch_related would only require two queries to get any amount of data from these two tables. This allows the number of properties to be infinite and you can query them any way you want.

```
class Derived(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='derived')
    value=models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    start=models.DateField(null=True)
    end=models.DateField(null=True)
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a great compromise for my database. Thinking ahead though, when the `fundamental` attributes are changed, I appreciate these can all be updated - however in some cases, some derived parameters may no longer be valid and would need to be removed. Is there a way to 'cascade' their deletion if they the calculation gives a `Nan` for example?

Comment: Note that this only allows one derived per project. You'd need a ForeignKey here, and a related_name 'derived_attributes', plus a name field to distinguish between different ones, and a `unique_together` involving project and name. On top of that, you have to handle all calculation methods in one model, unless you make proxy models for the different methods. Needs a good schema to make sense of it :)

Comment: This is now looking less appealing...! Is it feasible to generate a DataFrame of all studies and then `to_pickle()` it as a static file to then load when generating visualisations?

Comment: @Melvyn You're right. I meant to write foreignkey. I'll change it.